# Can editor be reference in hiring

Tags: recommendation-letter, reference-request, recruiting

I think it is clearly true that an editor of a journal can be a reference for the author of the paper he is managing since he could know the quality of the paper very well. So this question may seem redundant, but I just want to confirm that.

Comment: How much contact did you have with the editor you have in mind? Do you have any reason to believe that the editor does indeed remember you? Editors are usually busy people.

Comment: Why do you think this is clearly true? Being somebody's reference isn't usually based on only knowing the contents  of one paper.

Comment: @Snijderfrey, I mean only if the editor is impressed with the paper. I know normally this won't happen because an editor can handle many papers. But on rare occasions, if an editor is very impressed with a paper, can he recommend it?

Comment: In my experience, editors do not know the papers they publish very well, due to handling very many papers in limited time.

Comment: I had an experience that one of my submissions impressed the editor who handled it. Normally, an editor of a journal is responsible for prescreening papers submitted in his fields. If he finds no obvious problems and is interested in them, he will find referees for further review.

Answer (score 4):

As the editor of a journal, I'd feel very uncomfortable recommending any author. That's because I don't know them well enough. I could say they have submitted X paper to my journal and the reviews are great (which however is not a very valuable thing to say), or maybe that the paper has received a lot of citations (but anyone with Web of Science or Google Scholar can look that up for themselves). But I can't say more. Even if I'm an expert on their paper and it was a good piece of work, I have no idea what the research process was like, usually won't know which author was responsible for which part of the paper, etc. In the worst case scenario, the author was a gift author, and I have no way to tell.

So no: not a good idea for either the author or the editor.